# A more elegant solution for dealing with a single input for when array of arrays is missing keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following SQL data pull format available to me stored in the variable `$data`.

```
YEAR QUARTER CAT     NAME   ASSMT_TOTAL
2011    Q2  2011-Q2 Place-1 18
2011    Q3  2011-Q3 Place-1 22
2011    Q4  2011-Q4 Place-2 34
2011    Q3  2011-Q3 Place-2 21
2011    Q4  2011-Q4 Place-2 23
```

I'm trying to build an "final" array that will contain an array of arrays. Each array will look like this:

```
[name] => Place-1
[type] => line
[data] => Array
(
   [0] => 18
   [1] => 22
   ...
)
```

I've done the vast majority of it, but I'm struggling for the very few occasions where a `place` doesn't have a record for that particular category.

`$names` is an array of all the places and `$cats` is an array of all the available category names (`2011-Q2`).

```
  foreach($names as $s)
  {
    foreach($cats as $c)
    {
      $temp['name'] = $s;
      $temp['type'] = 'line';
      foreach($data as $d)
      {
        if($s === $d['NAME'] && $c === $d['CAT'])
        {
          $temp['data'][] = (int)$d['ASSMT_TOTAL'];
          break;
        }
        //$temp['data'][] = 0;
      }
    }
    $final[] = $temp;
    unset($temp);
  }
```

The above works well, except for dealing with those odd times that a site doesn't have a corresponding category. For example in my sample data, `place-2` doesn't have a CAT for 2011-Q2. How would I insert a zero in this case. I also wondered about a more elegant solution for the double for loop situation.

Comment: So is there an overall array for category?

Comment: @nerdlyist if understand you correctly. Yes my $cats array is an array of type ['2011-Q2', '2011-Q3',...]. Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you allready have a list of $cats you can compare your row category (I assume $d['CAT']) against that array and make it a corner case.

```
$catFoundMarker = false;
foreach($data as $d)
{
    if($s === $d['NAME'] && $c === $d['CAT'])
    {
          $temp['data'][] = (int)$d['ASSMT_TOTAL'];
          $catFoundMarker = true;
          break;
    }
}
if(!$catFoundMarker){
    $temp['data'][] = 0;
}
```

You can create a similar corner case for when 'NAME' is not there.

EDIT: sorry, updates a mistake in in_array function
EDIT2: updated solution

Comment: I'm not sure this will work because the `$d['CAT']` will exist for other rows.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your data a bit, I've updated the solution to work in a way, that if a category for name is not found within that loop of foreach it will assign a 0. This process will repeat for all cetegories in you defined array.

Comment: Thanks! Although out of the scope of this question, do you think there is a more elegant solution for this problem, maybe that doesn't involve two for loops?

Comment: Possibly, but it's 17:50 here and my head is not working as it's supposed to after a day of work (and it's time to go home). I will have a think about that and update the answer if I come up with something.